# select table and replace column fields by value from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have been working in ms SQL from the last 3 year, I am new in MySQL, recently we have some MySQL requirement to select a table and replace column fields by value from another table.
I have converted working ms SQL query to MySQL. while executing MySQL query getting an exception. attached table description.here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJOuQ.png)
Please advise me on this.

Following are my tried queries

```
SET  @v_Type := 'Account'; // where condition type =account

SET  @select := 'SELECT';

SET  @columns:= (  SELECT  CONCAT('CONVERT(' , `ColDataType` , ', Col' , CONVERT(VARCHAR, `ColNum`) , ') AS [' , `ColName` , '],') FROM    `Names`  WHERE   `TYPE` = @v_Type FOR XML PATH('') )

SET @where:='FROM `Data` WHERE [Type] = ''' + @v_Type + '''' 

SET @statement = CONCAT(@select,@columns,@where);

PREPARE myStatement FROM @statement;
EXECUTE myStatement;
```

While executing I got the error like

> Query: set @columns:= ( SELECT CONCAT('CONVERT(' , `ColDataType` , ', Col' , CONVERT(VARCHAR, `ColNum`) , ') AS [' , `ColName` , '],') ...
>
> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR, `ColNum`) , ') AS [' , `ColName` , '],') FROM    `Name' at line 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CONVERT()` cannot use `VARCHAR` as a datatype to convert to. Use `CHAR` instead. And it uses `CONVERT(expression, datatype)` arguments order, not backward.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have tried the above convert () in to query but still has some exceptions follows,   SET  @columns:= ( 
                SELECT  CONCAT('CONVERT(' , `ColDataType` , ', Col' , CONVERT( `ColNum`,CHAR) , ') AS [' , `ColName` , '],')
                FROM    `Names`
                WHERE   `TYPE` = ''+@v_Type+'' FOR XML PATH('')
            )      exception is  Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'XML PATH('')
            )

Comment: Please create fiddle instead of tables image (or at least replace the image with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts). And check tag validity - MySQL will NOT understand the `FOR XML PATH('')` construction and `+` as concatenation operator, this is SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('col', colnum, ' ', colname)),
               ' FROM data',
               ' WHERE type = ?')
INTO @sql
FROM names
WHERE type = @v_type
GROUP BY type;
PREPARE myStatement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE myStatement USING @v_type;
DROP PREPARE myStatement;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d07352084926ea1458fdec3aae6d3f1)

Comment: one more doubts to clear regarding the same issue. I want to replace field names with values that are from another table. I tried but its only showing one field value.want to show all fields with the respective name. please refer the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73c4dd0f2daffa82100c8e11689748a6 link

Comment: @MuhasseenaTU [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffc905eb3ca4aa573fd31371752ca116)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but now my requirement is some more complex than the above.https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed699eac15e24ae12a07f6ef97f6e640

Comment: okay. please refer the qn- .https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259386/select-table-and-replace-column-fields-by-value-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql